# Vue.js - calculated value from method doesn't display in looped list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I feel like this is a timing thing, but not necessarily an async thing. I am looping through an object and displaying a list of items. For one of the values I need to calculate it with a method.

The values directly on the item object display fine, but the calculated one never shows up, even though I can console.log it and it's there.

I've trying changing keys top to rerender the list but no luck. I tried making it a computed property but ran into "not a function" issues.

```
<ul>
  <li
    v-for="(item, index) in list"
    :key="index"
    class="list-wrap"
  >
    <span> 
      {{ item.name }} <---- this value shows every time.
    </span>
      <span class="location">
        {{ getLocation(item.Location[0]) }} <---- this "calculated" value returns only sometimes.
      </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

getLocation method:

```
methods: {
  getLocation(loc) { // id coming from item in loop
    this.locations.forEach((location) => { // loop through locations obj, match id, return location name.
      let match;
      if (location.id === loc) {
        match = location.name;
        console.log(match); <---- present / correct on every refresh
        return match; <--- not rendering
      }
    });
  },
},
```

// list is created in async api call

```
async getCurUserTransfers() {
  await airtableQuery
    .getTableAsync("Transfers", 100, "Grid view")
    .then((data) => {
      this.list = data.filter( // list is a filtered table.
        (transfer) =>
          transfer.fields.User === this.curUserNicename ||
          transfer.fields.User === this.curUserDisplayName
      );
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice with calculated fields is using computed property, so you should add a computed one called `listWithLocation` then loop through it :

```
computed:{
     listWithLocation(){

     return this.list.map( item=>{
        item.itemLocation=this.getLocation(item.Location[0]);// add field itemLocation and use the method already defined
         return item;
    }) 
}
}
```

template :

```
<ul>
  <li
    v-for="(item, index) in listWithLocation"
    :key="index"
    class="list-wrap"
  >
    <span> 
      {{ item.name }} 
    </span>
      <span class="location">
        {{item.itemLocation}}
      </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

the method :

```
methods: {
  getLocation(loc) { 
    return this.locations.find((location) => { // this returns the matched location
     
     return location.id === loc;
      
    });
  },
},
```

Comment: The problem is, the object for the v-for loop is a different object than the one I'm looping through to find the match. I'll see if I can make it work though. The template v-for loop needs to be the "list" object and the object to check against needs to be the "locations" object.

Comment: i think the problem is in the method

Comment: my code is a bit more complex than the example I gave so I'm working with your code to see if I can get it to work. The main v-for list (listWithLocation in your code) is generated at created() in an async api call. So, in the computed prop list is undefined initially, then is present on updated(). I'm getting a  `"TypeError: this.list.map is not a function"` error. I'm not sure how to make the computed prop wait until updated.

Comment: `list` is an object? if yes please provide a snippet

Comment: I added the api call method (which gets called `created()`) to the bottom of my original question.

Comment: no need to use `async/await` since you're using then block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218784/discussion-between-kirk-ross-and-boussadjra-brahim).

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` statement in the anonymous function that nested in your method. So, main function have no returned values.

And if you need a computed fields, you must declare the computed field in specific array that called as `computed`. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html